# Programmatically reject a call on the BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, call

I'm trying to programmatically reject a call on a BlackBerry, with Java + JDE.
I'm intercepting the `callIncoming` event, and in there I need to do something to reject a call from a specific number.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: no :) just an app that interprets calls from a specific number as a way to make the phone do something. So, it is not a "real call" that the user should answer. The app should reject it, and do something...

Comment: I would love to have an easy block for 'my second and last call' or 'free minutes to India' since I know the numbers they use (area codes anyway) but still answer them 1 in 4 times.

Comment: I would think that there wouldn't be a way to programmatically do this since it could be abused rather easily.

Comment: It could also be useful for a few things. Like if you are sending some important data, and you aren't on a 3G network. Incoming calls suspend all other data service activities.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find an API for directly rejecting the call in progress. However, you could explore a hack where you inject a keypress of the Hangup/Disconnect button (see `EventInjector`).

As to determining the phone number, you could use `Phone.getCall(callId).getDisplayPhoneNumber()` or `Phone.getActiveCall().getDisplayPhoneNumber()`.

Comment: Sounds like a "good" hack :) Just curious - don't do Blackberry since I develop on WM - but, do you have to make sure you send the "hangup-button" to the correct window, and does this not matteR?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than the `EventInjector`. The "security" layout of the BlackBerry API does not allow to hang up / reject a call. We tried to find a solution for this issue for 2 years.

Comment: When using event Injector, the call is blocked after 1 second approximately. So the device rings. How to set the ringer to silent mode? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using the incoming call listener, and notification APIs you can reject a call programmatically.

There is a topic discussing it on the blackberry developer forums, you can find it [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=40388&query.id=776291#M40388)

Answer (score 0):

try this

[How to disconnect a call in blackberry](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/how-to-disconnect-a-call-in-blackberry/)